# Python-Gitlab list projects and groups by name

Tags: python-2.7, gitlab, gitlab-ce

I am trying to list the project list by names not by ID#. This goes the same with listing the groups by name not by ID#.

I tried running some python-gitlab codes with python 2.7 version but I only get the ID#.

```
projects = gl.projects.list()
groups = gl.groups.list()
```

These two lines only gives the ID# of the projects and the groups but that's not what I want. What I want to know if it's possible to only get the name listed in groups and projects. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

There is an attribute called "attributes". Try the following:

```py
for project in gl.projects.list():
    # print everything
    print(project.attributes)
    # or a single attribute
    print(project.attributes['name'])
```

The same for groups:

```py
for group in gl.groups.list():
    # print everything
    print(group.attributes)
    # or a single attribute
    print(group.attributes['name'])
```

Comment: This works great! How would you return the list as the print statement prints the list of project names and group names? I tried the return statement but I cannot get the list as print statement would do it. I tried with append syntax as well but I am not getting it right. I get [u'pro1', u'pro2', ..] I just one something like... pro1 and pro2 like a list.

Comment: It is not clear to me what your current problem is. You already tried to append to a list within the `for` loop? Initializing a list before the loop and then doing `myList.append(group.attributes['name'])` in the loop should work.

Comment: I am coming back to this. Why does this even print the subgroups as well? I only want to print the groups not the subgroups from git site.

Answer (score 0):

Use [pagination](https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api-usage.html?highlight=pagination#pagination) if you have more than 20 projects in the group

```
    gl = gitlab.Gitlab('https://gitlab.com', private_token='Token')
    group = gl.groups.get(group_id, lazy=True)
    project_lst=group.projects.list(as_list=False)  #pagination
    for item in project_lst:
        project_id = gl.projects.get(item.attributes['id'])
        ......................................
        ......................................
```